# Azure AD B2C no javascript notice

Tags: active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am suddenly experiencing a brief flash of the following after I log into my site utilizing Azure ADB2C. However, I do have javascript enabled. Any ideas?

[image]

UPDATE

Here is one of the properties of the policy I'm using. Enforcing javascript is off.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a page contract version (javascript enabled in the B2C policy)? If so what version? Does it happen on other PCs?

Comment: @JasSuri I updated my question with an image from the properties page in Azure ADB2C. And to answer your second question, I believe that this is happening in only one browser (the Chromium preview version of Edge), it doesn't *appear* to be happening in Chrome. But it is a very quick flash and then the page redirects without any input from the user.